# Importing old mysql database dump into MariaDB docker container fails: Table 'user' already exists

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I'm trying to import an older (~version 5) server into a MariaDB docker container.

I created a dump using the mysqldump command (with --all-databases), and when I try to import it I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 2071: Table 'user' already exists
```

I'm trying to import into a brand new container, using the standard command:

```
 mysql -uroot -p  < [sqldump].sql
```

I'm a novice when it comes to SQL and was wondering if I'm missing something obvious, or if there is some real incompatibility.

I'd really appreciate your advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Delete the existing `user` table?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't really exist. I still went through with the whole thing (drop, flush and commit) to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your dump script wants to overwrite the system "mysql" database that contains users and privilege information. If that's really what you want to do, you can run `mysqldump` again with the `--add-drop-database` option, then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after import. I wouldn't recommend that though, especially if the databases are running different versions.

A better option would be to explicitly choose which databases you want to export by passing their names to the `--databases` argument, excluding DBs like "mysql", "information_schema" and "performance_schema". You would then grant privileges to the newly imported DBs as needed.

Another quick option would be to edit your existing dump file in a text editor and just take out the part that wants to create the "mysql" tables (including "user" and others).

Comment: It sounds like the dump is not the same version as the target system?  In that case there may be modifications to the `mysql` table schemas that would lead to trouble.  So, do not reload `mysql` or `information_schema` or `performance_schema` or `sys`.

Comment: THANK YOU, @Google Fail!  I was attempting to "restore" a complete database dump from `mysqld  Ver 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` to `mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.9-MariaDB` and am glad I heeded your *A better option would be...* advice.  Otherwise I would have "restored" user and several other tables in forms not compatible with my target database engine.

Comment: You’re welcome! @CODE-REaD

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with Docker and probably doesn't belong under serverfault. The answer is here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/285253/93071